# Anyone know how to check the hotkeys in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Menu gives some, any full docs or windows to show the hotkeys in the visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have [list](http://www.mssoftwareconsulting.com/msswc/blog/post/Reformat-Code-in-Visual-Studio.aspx) of hotkeys

And `Tools->Options->Environment->KeyBoard` - here you can assign hotkeys

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard in VS 2008 and 2010